# Use case for F# Enumeration Type Constraint?

Tags: f#

According to the documentation, an enumeration type constraint of the form 
`: enum<underlying-type>` is "not intended for common use". What would be the uncommon use it is meant for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing that jumps to mind is wrapping the members of `System.Enum` with strongly typed wrappers:

```
// gets all underlying values for which an enum is defined
let definedVals<'a, 'b when 'a : enum<'b>> = 
  System.Enum.GetValues(typeof<'a>) 
  |> Seq.cast<'a> 
  |> Seq.map (LanguagePrimitives.EnumToValue)

let ints = definedVals<System.ConsoleColor,_>
```

Comment: Had to think about this one for a while, but understand now that it's a very good example. Thanks.
What had me puzzled for a while is that System.Enum.GetValues() doesn't appear to require the constraint at all, but LanguagePrimitives.EnumToValue does. I guess it's down to the fact that the former is in the general use .NET libraries and can't know about F# constraints. On the other hand, type constraints are not unique to F# (C# generics have them), so I think there should be a way to make them work cross-language. 
Anyway, as far as my original question goes, it's been answered.